# How to bind numeric keypad keys in TextMate?

Tags: macos, keyboard, textmate, key-bindings

I often use TextMate on a desktop Mac with a full (old-style) Macintosh keyboard with a full numeric keypad.  I'd like to be able to bind menu item keys, macro key triggers and other actions to some of those numeric keypad keys.

I understand I can do this for some Cocoa (?) text editing commands in a ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict file, but for Macros the TextMate dialog box doesn't distinguish between numeric keypad and main keypad keys with the same name. Ditto for the OS/X keyboard shortcuts preference pane used to change TextMate menu item keys.

Should I be trying to customize some of the core bundles instead?

Any advice much appreciated,

Stu

Answer (score 0):

> I understand I can do this for some Cocoa (?) text editing commands in a ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict file

This is the key.  TextMate does use this file, but in addition it has its *own version* that may be used to override settings or provide unique actions.  You can even call some TextMate functions (selectors) directly through this method.

I recommend copying the default version from `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict` to `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict` and modifying it there.

Unfortunately, calling Bundle macros is a challenge... but I think it may be possible through some clever combinations of commands...

```
("insertText:"," keypad1.sh","selectWord:","executeCommand:")
```

Then, if you add into your source bundle the default values of the commands (in Support/bin) --- keypad1.sh returns 1... --- you can have customized commands in the Bundles you're interested in modifying.

I haven't tried this, but I think it may just work...

Comment: Thanks Matt -- this is a clever approach which I'll try out.